# data:image/jpeg;base64 how to get its width and height in pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you get the width and height in pixels image which its src is in data:image/jpeg;base64 ?

Didn't succeed using setting img.src to it and then calling width().

```
var img = jQuery("<img src="+oFREvent.target.result+">");
img.width() // = 0
```

Comment: Did you wait for the image to load?

Comment: @Musa, Don't think so, look at my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait for the image to be loaded (or complete, if cached). This will result in an asynchronous callback operation:

```
// pure JS:

var img = new Image();
img.src = myDataString;
if (img.complete) { // was cached
    alert('img-width: '+img.width);
}
else { // wait for decoding
    img.onload = function() {
       alert('img-width: '+img.width);
    }
}
```

Note: I once had the same problem with a project using jQuery. jQuery doesn't provide an access to the image directly enough just after you have created it. It seems, it's not possible to be done, but in pure JS. But you could try a timeout-loop and wait for the img-width to have a value (and catch any loading/decoding errors).

[Edit, see also comments] Why this works (why there is no race-condition):

JS is single-threaded, meaning there's only one part of code executed at a given time. Any events will be queued until the current scope is exited and will only fire then. Thanks to late-binding, any listeners will be evaluated only then (after the current scope has been executed). So the handler will be present and listening as soon as the onload-Event is fired, regardless, if the listener was setup before or after setting the src-attribute. In contrast to this, the complete-flag is set as soon as the src-attribute is set.

Comment: caching isn't an issue, as base64 images won't be cached !

Comment: hmm, are you sure for any future? better handle this edge case now and for ever...

Comment: Yes I'm sure, the image isn't cached, but if the file with the base64 string is static, like a .js file or .html file, and the headers are set correctly, that file, with the base64 string, will be cached, but not the same way as a browser would cache images, so the complete handler has no meaning.

Comment: @adaneo: Just because the internal image data is constructed from a base64 text string rather than using a TCP/IP connection, doesn't necessarily mean the caching subsystem is bypassed. I'm not saying that it definitely serves a useful purpose in this case, but there is insufficient evidence in your argument to guarantee that it's not used.

Comment: Anyway – without checking the complete-flag the code becomes even simpler. But I wouldn't guarantee for browser internals in two years from now. (So, you may wake up and the site has just stopped working with some images in some erratic cases and you haven't any clue. Better be defensive from the very beginning and have your future sleep. ;-))

Comment: @adeneo I have seen base64 images cached (in chrome)

Comment: Just a real world example: We were quite sure that a GET-request with url-parameters wouldn't be cached, if no caching-headers were provided (because the specs said so). Then came Safari Mobile (iOS) and everything that did rely on this stopped working. In case of caching and the evolution of mobile browsers, you can't be sure 100%.

Comment: @Musa - yes, chrome actually caches base64 strings, not sure how, but when just loading google.com you can see the Google logo etc. which are base64 strings, are cached somehow. Still not sure if they would fire the complete handler, but that's irrelevant as the onload handler will fire in all browsers except IE even when the image is cached, and IE certainly doesn't cache base64, so there is no issue as IE is the only browser that has issues with cached images and need the complete handler as well.

Comment: @adeneo For an image, there are several levels of cache: the binary source-information, the decoded RGB-image, the instance with its specific scaling. In case that the decoded image (the RGB binary) would be cached (which would make some sense even with data-urls) the image would be complete instantaneously.

Comment: True enough, but if the image isn't cached, you've just created a race condition by setting the source before the onload handler ?

Comment: It's my common image-preloading scheme for some years now and I never had an issue. Even with data-urls. I think it's because the JS is single threaded, so the script is blocked to wait for the instance and then for the src-attribute. By then, any complete-state would be present. Writing to the onload-property is basically just another way to an eventListener and would be active/called just after the thread/task/function is exited. So there should not be a race condition.

Comment: To make this more clear: Any events will be queued until the current scope is exited and will only fire then. Thanks to late-binding, any listeners will be evaluated only then (after the current scope has been executed). So the handler will be present and listening as soon as the onload-Event is fired, regardless, if the listener was setup before or after setting the src-attribute. In contrast to this, the complete-flag is set as soon as the src-attribute is set.

Comment: @adeneo – your code at jsfiddle fails for me with Chrome 28.0.1500.71 (Mac) while hitting the location for another page-load. So caching is definitely an issue with current Chrome, even with base64-encoded images. (Besides: Setting the complete-flag rather than firing a load-event is also a common behavior with Safari for some years, not IE and Chrome only.)

Comment: @masswerk I think you are mixing functions and variables/properties when it comes to global scope late binding. You can see this by defining `function x() ..` versus `var = function x() ..` (or use a property on the window object). If the latter comes after where `x()` is invoked it will be undefined while the first will invoke no matter where it's defined (in same or parent scope). `onload` won't be defined at the same time functions are, not before the interpreter reaches that line. See f.ex here where z() would be like onload: http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/2NwzY/

Comment: @adeneo My argument was about threads: the event fires only after the defining function was left (because the image-object didn't exist before). Only then the event bubbles and reaches any listeners. (There is no concurrent execution in JS! – with the exception of web workers, but these are separated from the DOM, so this is a different story.)

Answer (score 5):

This will work :

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    alert(this.width);
}
img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAA.......";
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GkZ3T/)

I made sure the base64 was valid by converting an image [**here**](http://base64img.com/#encode), and the onload function should come before setting the source of the image.